# Relative layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a newbie in android who has started android just today.I am facing some problem in Layouts.
I want the layout to be as follows.

```
   1(TextView)     2(TextView)
   3(EditView)     4(EditView)
```

Here is what I have tried.The Top 1 & 2 represents TextView and 3
&4 represents EditView.Can we achieve this only with relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/amicare"

    tools:context="com.example.ambulancetrack.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg_no"

        android:id="@+id/tvRegNo"
        android:textColor="#21F6D0"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RAHAT Phone No."
        android:textColor="#21F6D0"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNo"

        />
   <EditText 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvRegNo"

       android:background="#1E4F56"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:id="@+id/evRegNo"
       />

     <EditText 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/evRegNo"

       android:background="#1E4F56"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:id="@+id/evPhoneNo"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help!!!Thanks in Advance

Comment: The EditView Over lap on one another

Comment: Yes It can be achieved through linear layout.Just trying a hand at relative layout

Comment: give wrap to edittext

Comment: If i give Warp to Edit text the edittext grows automatically if the length is grater i.e if length is some x characters it wraps automatically

Comment: Yes, we can do that by using a single RelativeLayout, without any other useless layout.

Comment: So @frank can you please help me with relative layout

Comment: Add a View in the center. Then add all the views **relative** to it (toLeftOf, toRightOf) and to them (below). To note that `fill_parent` is **deprecated**. Use `match_parent`, instead.

Answer (score 3):

Ckeck this variant (in your case):

**UPDATE:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/amicare"

tools:context="com.example.ambulancetrack.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/reg_no"

    android:id="@+id/tvRegNo"
    android:textColor="#21F6D0"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RAHAT Phone No."
    android:textColor="#21F6D0"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNo"

    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvRegNo"

    android:background="#1E4F56"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/evRegNo"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/evPhoneNo"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/evPhoneNo" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
    android:background="#1E4F56"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/evPhoneNo"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can archive this using `LinearLayout` also using `android:layout_weight`, like:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Text View 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Text View 2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Text View 3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Text View 4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ambulancetrack.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="reg_no"
        android:textColor="#21F6D0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RAHAT Phone No."
        android:textColor="#21F6D0"

        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/evRegNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvRegNo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1E4F56"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/evPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/evRegNo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1E4F56"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Test it and accept the answer if it is useful.

Comment: You can add a comment as a reason for down voting.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abce"
            android:id="@+id/tvRegNo"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvPhoneNo"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RAHAT Phone No."

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNo"

            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvRegNo"
           android:hint="avc"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/evRegNo"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="avcd"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/evRegNo"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/evPhoneNo"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is right,we can use one `RelativeLayout`  to achieve your goal,but your last EditText's attrs maybe wrong.Please try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/amicare"

    tools:context="com.example.ambulancetrack.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg_no"

        android:id="@+id/tvRegNo"
        android:textColor="#21F6D0"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RAHAT Phone No."
        android:textColor="#21F6D0"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNo"

        />
   <EditText 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvRegNo"

       android:background="#1E4F56"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:id="@+id/evRegNo"
       />

     <EditText 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
       android:background="#1E4F56"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:id="@+id/evPhoneNo"
       />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Just add

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
android:layout_below="@+id/tvPhoneNo"
```

to make sure `evPhoneNo` layouts below of `tvPhoneNo` and align left of `tvPhoneNo`.

Answer (score 1):

Change main layout type to **Linear** with **Vertical** orientation. Then add 2 more Linear layout with **Horizontal** orientation inside and put your Textviews there. Use Weight attribute to control the size of each layout. Like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add one more layout to you main Vertical layout and set it **weight** to 10, so it will take most space and your textviews will be close to each other. Dont forget to set `android:layout_height="0dp"`of your inner layouts to make **weight** work right.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work. You can change text color and other attributes as you want.but this is the basic structure of your question

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="137dp"
            android:text="EditView"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText"
            android:text="EditView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```